# alarm trigger immediately and broadcast receiver methods get called immediately

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

**alarm trigger immediately first time working according to time we set but then whatever the time we set it trigger immediately**

**alarm code**

```
 mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener((view, hourOfDay, minute) -> {

        mHour = hourOfDay;
        mMinute = minute;

        //Globals.showToast(getActivity(), hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

    });
```

**below code will be called on a button click**

```
int rcode = new Random().nextInt();
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (alarmManager != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
         pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getActivity(), rcode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);


        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, --mMonth);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
       /* SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy hh:mm:a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Globals.showToast(getActivity(), simpleDateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));*/
// Calculate notification time
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long currentTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
        long diffTime = mCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime;

        // Start alarm using notification time
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + diffTime,
                pendingIntent);
```

> using above code i m setting alarm but it works perfect only for first time alarm setting.  then after using whatever i m setting alarm it triggers immediately.

**below receiver toast show immediately**

**receiver code**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Globals.showToast(context, "Alarm Time");

}
```

}

Comment: I think perhaps you are getting mixed up between asynchronous and synchronous programming? When the user chooses the time, the OnTimeChangedListener will be called or the lambda in this case. But the only thing that will happen is that the 2 assignments will be executed "mHour = hourOfDay; mMinute = minute;". The rest of the code below the listener is not going to be executed unless you put it in a function and call it from the OnTimeChangedListener.

Comment: @Elletlar I have edited the question to make it clear how code is used. and i literally have no idea why this problem ocurring.

Comment: Thanks. Is the computed value "diffTime" set to the expected value after the new time is chosen?

Comment: @Elletlar yes "diffTime" is latest time for every new click

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem?

Comment: @DavidWasser yes by using this Calendar calendar=new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the problem:

```
mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, --mMonth);
```

This will work the first time, but the next time the value of `mMonth` will be 1 less than it should be, because you have decreased the value of `mMonth`. In this case, the trigger time will have already passed, causing the alarm to trigger immediately.

Try this instead:

```
mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth - 1);
```

Comment: i have changed this implementation and used Calendar calendar=new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day);   and your solution may be correct.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can "accept" it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This gives me some reputation points and may help others in the future. It also gets the question off the list of unanswered questions.